# Error when using Linq to CRM with Early Bound Entities

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

I am writing a plugin in CRM 2011. I am trying to use Linq to CRM to retrieve an entity record, here is the code snippet:

```
Entity legalcase = new Entity("lgl_legalcase");
legalcase = legalDataContext.Lgl_legalcaseSet.FirstOrDefault(l => l.Lgl_legalcaseId == legalCaseGUID);
```

It is throwing an error on this line saying that it cannot convert from type Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Entity to type Legal.Entities.Lgl_legalcase. I have verified that this plugin works fine when using a Retrieve method instead of the LINQ syntax, but I would like to get it working with LINQ. Does anyone know why this is throwing an error?

Comment: For the moment, assume the error is valid...write `.ToEntity<Lgl_legalcase>()` at the end and see what happens.  In plugins, this is often the solution.  I won't go into why this is the case or other strategies for fixing it.

Comment: I tried adding this to the end, but I still receive the same error.

Comment: what do you get with `var something = legalDataContext.Lgl_legalcaseSet.FirstOrDefault(l => l.Lgl_legalcaseId == legalCaseGUID)` ?  It was my assumption this would return a `Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Entity` type.

Comment: Using the var something statement, I still receive the same error.

Comment: if the answer I have submitted below answers your question, please mark it as the answer; otherwise, please submit more information.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast:

```cs
Entity legalcase = new Entity("lgl_legalcase")
legalcase = (Entity)legalDataContext.Lgl_legalcaseSet.FirstOrDefault(l => l.Lgl_legalcaseId == legalCaseGUID);
```

or define legalcase as `Lgl_legalcase` type

```cs
Lgl_legalcase legalcase = new Lgl_legalcase();
legalcase = legalDataContext.Lgl_legalcaseSet.FirstOrDefault(l => l.Lgl_legalcaseId == legalCaseGUID);
```

Comment: I still receive the same error when trying either of these methods.

Comment: Which error exactly you get? because you want to convert early bound to late bound, but the error you wrote in your question looks like you are doing the opposite

Comment: This is the actual error description: "Cannot convert from type Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Entity to type Legal.Entities.Lgl_legalcase."

Answer (score 1):

I just refactored my code such that the Proxies are now in a library referenced by my plugins; and after the refactor, I receive this error message.

After searching the internet for 20 seconds, I found the following suggested fix:
add `[assembly: Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.ProxyTypeAssemblyAttribute()]` to the plugin assembly

My VM is acting up and won't allow me to Copy&Paste, otherwise, I would share the link from Microsoft social and credit the person who I copied this from.